# jquery mobile swipe function only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery mobile for sideswipe gestures on ipad.

The below code is in a file referenced in my html file.

My html file has:

```
<div data-role="page" id="device1">
<!--content for this part of html page -->
</div>
<!--more divs with incrementing id -->
<div data-role="page" id="device4">
<!--content for this part of html page -->
</div>
```

This format is used in multiple html files.

I use this code (found on stackoverflow) - didnt want to post on old thread.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.ui-slider-handle').on('touchstart', function(){
        // When user touches the slider handle, temporarily unbind the page turn handlers
        doUnbind();
    });

    $('.ui-slider-handle').on('mousedown', function(){
        // When user touches the slider handle, temporarily unbind the page turn handlers
        doUnbind();
    });

    $('.ui-slider-handle').on('touchend', function(){
        //When the user let's go of the handle, rebind the controls for page turn
        // Put in a slight delay so that the rebind does not happen until after the swipe has been triggered
        setTimeout( function() {doBind();}, 100 );
    });

    $('.ui-slider-handle').on('mouseup', function(){
        //When the user let's go of the handle, rebind the controls for page turn
        // Put in a slight delay so that the rebind does not happen until after the swipe has been triggered
        setTimeout( function() {doBind();}, 100 );
    });

    // Set the initial window (assuming it will always be #1
    window.now = 1;

    //get an Array of all of the pages and count
    windowMax = $('div[data-role="page"]').length; 

   doBind();
});


// Functions for binding swipe events to named handlers
function doBind() {
    $('div[data-role="page"]').on("swipeleft", turnPage); 
    $('div[data-role="page"]').on("swiperight", turnPageBack);
}

function doUnbind() {
    $('div[data-role="page"]').die("swipeleft", turnPage);
    $('div[data-role="page"]').die("swiperight", turnPageBack);
}

// Named handlers for binding page turn controls
function turnPage(){
    // Check to see if we are already at the highest numbers page            
    if (window.now < windowMax) {
        window.now++
        $.mobile.changePage("#device"+window.now, "slide", false, true);
    }
}

function turnPageBack(){
    // Check to see if we are already at the lowest numbered page
    if (window.now != 1) {
        window.now--;
        $.mobile.changePage("#device"+window.now, "slide", true, true);
    }
}

// Named handlers for binding page turn controls
function navigate_without_swipe(page){
    // Check to see if we are already at the highest numbers page            
    $.mobile.changePage("#device"+page, "slide");
}
```

Please tell me why I need to reload the page for this javascript to work

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using $(document).ready

Thats a JQuery event.

Jquery Mobile has its own loading events because pages are loaded by JQM using AJAX which means that event is not fired.

I think you probably want to do that in a [pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) but check the documentation to see if there is amore appropriate event for your situation.

[JQuery Mobile documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)

Comment: Still trying to work out how to post on here! I tried pageinit and pagechange events, but still no luck. How do you get a new line when doing one of these comments btw, I keep pressing enter and it submits